# jQuery modal form with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

Is there a way to use modal form in jQuery using multiple buttons?

Actually all buttons have the same name and ID. I just want that every time I click any button the modal form will pop up.

Let's just use the example from the jQuery below: having 3 buttons.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <style>
      body { font-size: 62.5%; }
      label, input { display:block; }
      input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
      fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
      h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
      div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
      div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
      div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
      .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
      .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
    </style>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var name = $( "#name" ),
        email = $( "#email" ),
        password = $( "#password" ),
        allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
        tips = $( ".validateTips" );
        function updateTips( t ) {
          tips
            .text( t )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
          setTimeout(function() {
            tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
          }, 500 );
        }
        function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
          if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + "." );
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
        function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
          if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( n );
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 300,
          width: 350,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            "Create an account": function() {
              var bValid = true;
              allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
              bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
              bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
              bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );
              bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
              // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
              bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
              bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );
              if ( bValid ) {
                $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                  "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
                  "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
                  "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
                  "</tr>" );
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          },
          close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
          }
        });
        $( "#create-user" )
          .button()
          .click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
        <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
        <form>
          <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
        <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
        <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
          <thead>
            <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Password</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>John Doe</td>
              <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
              <td>johndoe1</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
      <button id="create-user">Create new user1</button>
      <button id="create-user">Create new user2</button>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answered

**ID's should be unique on the page**, when you have multiple elements with same ID's, jQuery selects only the first one. That's because it doesn't have to bother looking for others as there isn't supposed to be any more – that might explain the weird behaviour you're experiencing.

Give different ID's to your buttons

If you want multiple elements to have the same functionality, give them the same class.

Comment: Thanks so much :), i can now catch up with the release of my mini project :)! I learn something new today :) which is use unique ID.

Answer (score 1):

> actually all buttons have same name and id?

`Id`s are always unique. Use `Class` instead.[More Info](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/).

```
 <button class ="create-user">Create new user</button>
 <button class ="create-user">Create new user1</button>
 <button class ="create-user">Create new user2</button>
```